# Photoshop with Bitlocker

Tags: encryption, adobe-photoshop, boot-partition

I found this [entry](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/incompatibilities) (Photoshop's activation software overwrites fixed drive adresses) in the TrueCrypt documentation that scares me quite a bit. How does Bitlocker handle this issue? Similarly, how does Windows handle this without partition (meta-)data being damaged?